# issues with alignment

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a html table whose headers need to be fixed. I am using bootstrap classes to make html headers fix, but i see many issues with that.
Please find the sample [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZcLSE/1412/).
Issues i'm facing are Header is not displayed starting from first column, word wrap is not applied for the columns header or the columns. Please advice. Is there any better way to solve this.

html code:

```
<div class="modal-body"  id="modal-body">
<table id="myTable" class="table table-fixedheader table-bordered table-striped"> <thead>
<tr class="row"><th class="col-md-7">Header1</th><th class="col-md-4">Header2</th><th class="col-md-3">Header3</th><th class="col-md-4">Header4</th></tr>
</thead><tbody>
<tr><td>1111</td><td>33333</td><td>1111</td><td>3333322222222222222222222222222222</td></tr>
<tr><td>1111</td><td>33333</td><td>1111</td><td>33333</td></tr>
<tr><td>112222222222222215555555551</td><td>33333</td><td>1111</td><td>33333</td></tr>         
<tr><td>1111</td><td>33333</td><td>1111</td><td>33333</td></tr>
<tr><td>1111</td><td>33333</td><td>1111</td><td>33333</td></tr>
<tr><td>1111</td><td>33333</td><td>1111</td><td>33333</td></tr>
<tr><td>1111</td><td>33333</td><td>1111</td><td>33333</td></tr>         
<tr><td>1111</td><td>33333</td><td>1111</td><td>33333</td></tr>
<tr><td>1111</td><td>33333</td><td>1111</td><td>33333</td></tr>
<tr><td>1111</td><td>33333</td><td>1111</td><td>33333</td></tr> <tr><td>1111</td><td>33333</td><td>1111</td><td>33333</td></tr>         
<tr><td>1111</td><td>33333</td><td>1111</td><td>33333</td></tr>
<tr><td>1111</td><td>33333</td><td>1111</td><td>33333</td></tr>
<tr><td>1111</td><td>33333</td><td>1111</td><td>33333</td></tr> <tr><td>1111</td><td>33333</td><td>1111</td><td>33333</td></tr>         
<tr><td>1111</td><td>33333</td><td>1111</td><td>33333</td></tr>
</tbody>  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

1.) The cells in your header `tr` have Bootstrap classes which add up to a width of 18 columns (7+4+3+4), but one row can only fit 12 columns in the bootstrap grid system.

2.) You write that wordwrap is not applied, but you don't have any CSS rules for wordwrap anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the information, in my application i have 16 columns each of different width. Few columns display text like comments, information etc.. and few columns display only numbers like count,percentage..Can i use bootstrap classes then?As bootstrap row can only fit 12columns..Please advice

Comment: The Bootstrap classes you are using all have percentage widths, and those are designed for a 12-column grid, see here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid If your classes add up to more than that, they will move to the next line (in a normal row - a table markup will probably force them to stay in one line, but their width still exceeds 100% width)

Comment: P.S.: You could of course use *other* bootstrap classes so that the sum adds up to 12, like 5+2+3+2...

Answer (score 1):

You're using class `.row` on one row only :

```
<tr class="row">
<th class="col-md-7">Header1</th>
<th class="col-md-4">Header2</th>
<th class="col-md-3">Header3</th>
<th class="col-md-4">Header4</th>
</tr>
```

You either use the same class on each row or just delete it and leave the rows without a class.

```
<tr></tr>
```

this would fix your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Only simple thing missed is using the same structure (Or CSS classes), I've checked the code from your fiddle and this should work for the scenario you've presented.

```
 <!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Launch demo modal
</button>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="modal-body">
                <table id="myTable" class="table table-fixedheader table-bordered table-striped table-scroll">
                    <thead>

                        <tr class="row">
                            <th class="col-md-3">Header1</th>
                            <th class="col-md-4">Header2</th>
                            <th class="col-md-3">Header3</th>
                            <th class="col-md-4">Header4</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr class="row">
                            <td class="col-md-3">1111</td>
                            <td class="col-md-4">33333</td>
                            <td class="col-md-3">1111</td>
                            <td class="col-md-4">5443545435354543</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="row">
                            <td class="col-md-3">1111</td>
                            <td class="col-md-4">33333</td>
                            <td class="col-md-3">1111</td>
                            <td class="col-md-4">5437665</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="row">
                            <td class="col-md-3">1111</td>
                            <td class="col-md-4">33333</td>
                            <td class="col-md-3">1111</td>
                            <td class="col-md-4">5435435443</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="row">
                            <td class="col-md-3">1111</td>
                            <td class="col-md-4">33333</td>
                            <td class="col-md-3">1111</td>
                            <td class="col-md-4">68678454</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="row">
                            <td class="col-md-3">1111</td>
                            <td class="col-md-4">786876</td>
                            <td class="col-md-3">8787876</td>
                            <td class="col-md-4">6765767</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="row">
                            <td class="col-md-3">7656765</td>
                            <td class="col-md-4">656456</td>
                            <td class="col-md-3">116611</td>
                            <td class="col-md-4">43434</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="row">
                            <td class="col-md-3">43243432434324342</td>
                            <td class="col-md-4">33344343233</td>
                            <td class="col-md-3">1111</td>
                            <td class="col-md-4">4343</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="row">
                            <td class="col-md-3">1111</td>
                            <td class="col-md-4">432434343243243</td>
                            <td class="col-md-3">1111</td>
                            <td class="col-md-4">432443</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="row">
                            <td class="col-md-3">1111</td>
                            <td class="col-md-4">333333</td>
                            <td class="col-md-3">111312312123121</td>
                            <td class="col-md-4">32112</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

Okay:

**For Word-wrap in continuous text**

add " word-break: break-all;" (see the CSS below)

**FOR Fixed Header**

Refer the 'table-scroll' class in the HTML markup above
AND
Add the following CSS:

```
.modal-body {
  /*max-height: calc(100vh - 210px);*/
  height:300px;
  width:90%;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-break: break-all;

}


.table-scroll tbody {
    position: absolute;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 400px;
}

.table-scroll tr {
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
    display: inline-table;
}

.table-scroll thead > tr > th {
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: @NBaua-No its not working. Please find the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ZcLSE/1414/ with your code. First thing is header is not fixed and second issue is word wrap is not applied for the data.

Answer (score 0):

repalce   this

```
 <tr class ="row" >
```

with this

```
  <tr>
```

your updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/girish28892/ZcLSE/1431/